How is Redis distributed lock better than using pessimistic or optimistic lock in Ticketmaster design?
I came across this article https://www.hellointerview.com/learn/system-design/answer-keys/ticketmaster which mentions use of distributed Redis lock to prevent double booking a seat. The article mentions it as the best solution over pessimistic/optimistic locking.
However, I think introducing Redis lock also introduces network delay along with an external additional component which increases the complexity of the design.
Pessimistic or optimistic locks won't have network delay.
What am I missing? Is using normal database locking mechanism (SELECT FOR UPDATE) really that bad for designs like ticketmaster?

Database locks are not designed to be long-lived.  They generally live for the life of a back-end transaction, not for human-time.   Human time (seconds to minutes) is an eternity for a database, and thousands (millions) of those locks would devastate database performance.
Furthermore, you would need an open database connection for each user of the system, utilizing huge memory and operating-systems (locks are tied to connections/transactions).  You would literally have to have a solution to route end-users back to the same application server, which has a set of open database connections so that they could re-connect to that same connection to complete the purchase.  The solution just wouldn't scale, and would break under any significant load.

If I am able to understand correctly, the scenario you have described is for pessimistic locking? can we build a scalable solution using optimistic locking?

Optimistic locking wouldn't work.   Optimistic locking throws the error at commit-time when the data changes outside the current transaction.   The scenario would lead to:  "I know you selected these seats 10 minutes ago, but they were purchased out from under you, sorry about your luck, try and find a new seat."  It would keep double-purchases from happening, but it would lose the "reserve" functionality.

Thanks for explaining. Curious what is the recommended solution for this (no double purchase + reserve functionality)?

Use persistent data with a TTL.  Put a field in the database (or in that with a reservation-id and an expiration date/time, which put in-session for the purchaser.   You then put in a sweeper process that regularly searches for tickets that have an expired reservation, but haven't been fully "purchased", and your remove that reservation-id and put them back into the pool of purchasable tickets.   The linked design proposes a "better" solution using distributed locks, but that's fairly unnecessary as databases are really quite good at managing concurrency.
